# Bootstrap modal data refresh

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to pass data from bootstrap modal to the ul element. It lets me to add multiple li elements but it is always the first li element and doesnt change. Please help.

```
<ul id="myList">
</ul>

<button type="button" id="btnLaunch" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Enter text:</p>
              <input type="text" id="txtInput">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal -->
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#btnLaunch').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });

  $('#btnSave').click(function() {

    var value = $('input').val();
     $("#myList").append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="'+ value +'" name="'+ value +'" value="'+ value +'" checked>'+ value +'</li>');

        $('#myModal').modal('hide');


  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 $('#txtInput').val();
```

instead of

```
 $('input').val();
```

You are using just input selector on every iteration which is too generic. You can use the Id selector from Jquery to grab the input element and get the new value out of it. Here is a working example.

```
 <script>
  $(function() {

   $('#btnLaunch').click(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });

   $('#btnSave').click(function() {

   var value = $('#txtInput').val();
   $("#myList").append('<li><input type="checkbox" id="'+ value +'" 
   name="'+ value +'" value="'+ value +'" checked>'+ value +'</li>');

   $('#txtInput').val('');

   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
 });
 </script>
```